# How do I import specific functions from a module explicitly?

Tags: powershell

This is for readability and safety (clobbering duplication functions) and finding a workaround for no namespace support with PowerShell modules.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Import-Module MyHelpers.psm1 -Functions "FuncOne" -as MyHelpers.Func-One

MyHelpers.Func-One -blah sfsdfsdf
```

This make it obvious where FuncOne lives. for larger scripts I consider this pretty serious requirement.

It would probably be good enough if I could at least explicitly define which functions I'm importing (without being able to rename them). At least I would see where they are coming from. Is there any support for this? If not then I'll just have to name all functions inside of MyHelpers like `MyHelpers.Func-One` but then PowerShell will complain the verb is wrong; would that also break other things too?

Comment: Use the `Function` parameter to restrict the function (s) you want to import. Use the `Prefix` parameter to add a prefix string to the functions. See [Import- module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) examples 5 and 6

Comment: Thats enough for me, I can accept as answer

Comment: I have posted it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my comment as answer:

You can use the `Function` parameter to restrict the function (s) you want to import.

Next, with the `Prefix` parameter you can add a prefix string to these imported functions.

See [Import- module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) examples 5 and 6

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478864/3905079) is correct, just want to point out also that you can fully qualify commands that you call by prefixing them with the module name already, for example:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

ActiveDirectory\Get-ADComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

or to your example:

```
Import-Module MyHelpers.psm1 -Functions "FuncOne" -as MyHelpers.Func-One

MyHelpers\Func-One -blah sfsdfsdf
```